# At a bus stop, frequency of bus is $20$ minutes. A passenger coming at random time write their waiting time. What is average waiting time?

Tags: probability

> The frequency of bus coming to a bus stop is $20$ minutes. Passengers
>   come there at random time. They write the time they waited for the
>   bus, as soon as the bus arrives they board the bus. What is the
>   average of waiting time of all the passengers?

Comment: Distribution is $\mathsf{Unif}(0, 20),$ which has mean $\mu = 10.$

Comment: ...and your attempt to solve this is?

Comment: I thought of answer like $\int_{0}^{20} f(t)dt$, where $f(t)$ is waiting time distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passengers could come $20$ minutes early, or $0$ minutes early, and from this problem, we can assume they are evenly scattered in between.

Then, the average waiting time must be $10$ minutes.